# Python struct.pack dropping a byte.

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

If I run the following using Python 3.3.1:

```
import struct
struct.pack('!Bhh', 1, 1, 10)
```

I get this result:

```
b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\n'
```

rather than the result I am expecting:

```
b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x0a\n'
```

Can anyone tell me where my missing byte has gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lost byte is right there; `\n` is character 10 in the ASCII table:

```
>>> chr(10)
'\n'
```

Instead of displaying it as `\x0a` it is displayed as a Python string literal escape code; other known escapes are also shown that way. Printable ASCII characters are shown as characters:

```
>>> struct.pack('!Bhh', 1, 1, 13)
b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\r'
>>> struct.pack('!Bhh', 1, 1, 9)
b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\t'
>>> struct.pack('!Bhh', 1, 1, 65)
b'\x01\x00\x01\x00A'
```

It might help to use [`binascii.hexlify()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) to convert your bytes to hexadecimal characters:

```
>>> from binascii import hexlify
>>> hexlify(struct.pack('!Bhh', 1, 1, 10))
b'010001000a'
```